# Python+xarray: Displaying datasets

Tags: python, dataset, coordinates, interpolation, python-xarray

I have a dataset, which I am to interpolate.

[Original dataset](https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_gfs_0p25_1hr.pl?dir=%2Fgfs.20230411%2F00%2Fatmos&file=gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f000&var_TMP=on&lev_2_m_above_ground=on&subregion=&toplat=51&leftlon=1&rightlon=4&bottomlat=47): a field with a graticule (latitude: 17, longitude: 13, step: 0.25x0.25 degrees) and 221 values within this graticule.

```
ds= xr.open_dataset('gfs.t00z.pgrb2.0p25.f000', engine='cfgrib')
print(ds['t2m'])

'''
Output:
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (latitude: 17, longitude: 13)>
[221 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
    time               datetime64[ns] ...
    step               timedelta64[ns] ...
    heightAboveGround  float64 ...
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 47.0 47.25 47.5 ... 50.5 50.75 51.0
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 1.0 1.25 1.5 1.75 ... 3.5 3.75 4.0
'''
```

I have to transform the field into a field with *graticule of a different latitude/longitude step* (1.9047x1.875 degrees):

```
ds_i = ds.interp(latitude=[48.5705, 50.4752],
                 longitude=[1.875, 3.75],
                 method="linear")
print(ds_i['t2m'])

'''
Output:
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (latitude: 2, longitude: 2)>
array([[281.84174231, 284.01994458],
       [281.00258201, 280.88313926]])
Coordinates:
    time               datetime64[ns] 2023-04-11
    step               timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    heightAboveGround  float64 2.0
    valid_time         datetime64[ns] 2023-04-11
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 48.57 50.48
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 1.875 3.75
'''
```

How do I **display the original and interpolated datasets** to compare them side by side and make sure I did everything right and achieved my goal?

Also, note that the interpolated coordinates are truncated (48.5705, 50.4752 compared to 48.57 50.48 in the output). Is there a way to keep the accuracy?

**Update thanks to the answer-solution:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion.

#### Create a dataset that looks like yours

```
import xarray as xr

ds_raw = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")
ds = ds_raw.air.isel(time=0)
print(ds)
```

->

```
<xarray.DataArray 'air' (lat: 25, lon: 53)>
array([[241.2    , 242.5    , 243.5    , ..., 232.79999, 235.5    ,
        238.59999],
       [243.79999, 244.5    , 244.7    , ..., 232.79999, 235.29999,
        239.29999],
       [250.     , 249.79999, 248.89   , ..., 233.2    , 236.39   ,
        241.7    ],
       ...,
       [296.6    , 296.19998, 296.4    , ..., 295.4    , 295.1    ,
        294.69998],
       [295.9    , 296.19998, 296.79   , ..., 295.9    , 295.9    ,
        295.19998],
       [296.29   , 296.79   , 297.1    , ..., 296.9    , 296.79   ,
        296.6    ]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 ... 25.0 22.5 20.0 17.5 15.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 ... 322.5 325.0 327.5 330.0
    time     datetime64[ns] 2013-01-01
```

#### Interpolate, just as you did

```
ds_interp = ds.interp(lat=[48.5705, 50.4752], lon=[301.875, 303.75], method="linear")
```

#### Plot

To compare the original data and the interpolated data, you could use `pcolormesh` to plot the original data and then `scatter` plot the new points that you interpolated to.

```
# plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vmin, vmax = ds.min(), ds.max()

# original grid
ds.plot.pcolormesh(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# stack to obtain 1D lon, 1D lat and 1D temperature
ds_interp_gridpoints = ds_interp.stack(gridpoint=["lon", "lat"])

# scatter plot inteprolated dataset
plt.scatter(
    ds_interp_gridpoints.lon,
    ds_interp_gridpoints.lat,
    c=ds_interp_gridpoints,
    vmin=vmin,
    vmax=vmax,
    s=100,
    ec="k",
)

plt.xlim(290, 320)
plt.ylim(45, 55)
plt.show()
```

[image: original data plus interpolated data]

#### Accuracy of coordinates

When printing a DataArray/ Dataset the coordinates are rounded automatically. The actual underlying data is not rounded, as can be seen by:

```
print(ds_interp.lat.values)

[48.5705 50.4752]
```

Comment: For some reason, **ds.plot.pcolormesh(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)** gives me error: *AttributeError: 'DatasetPlotAccessor' object has no attribute 'pcolormesh'*...

Comment: In your case: `ds.t2m.plot.pcolormesh(…)` in my case `ds` is actually a DataArray, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks! As far as I inderstood, this plots my initial array and the points of my interpolated array on top. But I need to visualise not only points themselves, but the actual temperature values at the points to make sure I did the interpolation correctly... Like, to see that the computed temperature at some interpolated point is really correct in relation to surrounding values.

Comment: Or maybe I did something wrong, because in `plt.scatter(...c=ds_i_gridpoints...)` I get the error *ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 't2m' --> ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not <xarray.Dataset>*. And I just replced the `c=ds_i_gridpoints` with color.

Comment: In my case `ds_i_gridpoints` is again a DataArray, not a Dataset. It is therefore array-like and its entries specify the color. The color is not constant. In your case, you would need `plt.scatter(...c=ds_i_gridpoints.t2m...)`. Then `ds_i_gridpoints.t2m` will specify the color of each point and you will be able to visually compare if the color of the datapoints matches the background structure of the field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This have worked after I corrected this and the following issue: `vmin, vmax` should have been replaced with `vmin=vmin.to_pandas().t2m, vmax=vmax.to_pandas().t2m` in `ds.t2m.plot.pcolormesh(...)` and `plt.scatter(...)` for it wanted float values. I've updated the question with the resulting image!